# On deleting C++ pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, new-operator, delete-operator

OK..so this confuses the hell out of me. I am dealing with some legacy C++ code parts of which I have a feeling are just not safe, but I am not 100% sure. Here's a snippet, for example of the risky stuff.

```
struct A {
    A() : a_ptr(0) {}
    A(some_type *ptr) : a_ptr(ptr) {}
    const some_type *a_ptr;
};

struct B {
    B() : b_ptr(0) {}
    B(some_type *ptr) : b_ptr(ptr) {}
    const some_type *b_ptr;
};

struct Data {
    Data(...) {//-Stuff that doesn't invole aptr_list or bptr_list;
    }
    ~Data() {
        for(std::vector<A*>::iterator itr = aptr_list.begin(); itr != aptr_list.end() ++itr) {
            delete *itr;
        }
        for(std::vector<B*>::iterator itr = bptr_list.begin(); itr != bptr_list.end() ++itr) {
            delete *itr;
        }
    }
    std::vector<A*> aptr_list;
    std::vector<B*> bptr_list;
private:
    Data(const Data&);
    Data& operator=(const Data&);
};
```

Then in the implementation, I find:

```
void some_func(...) {
    //-Inside some function
    Data& d = get_data(...);
    ...
    for(...) {
         some_type *sptr = dynamic_cast<some_type*>(a_source_of_some_type_pointer);
         A* a = new A(sptr);
         B* b = new B(sptr);
         d.aptr_list.push_back(a);
         d.bptr_list.push_back(b);
    }
}
```

I am a little uneasy about the same pointer `sptr` being used in the implementation above; would this create problems when the destructor of `Data` is invoked? On the other hand, it looks like we have two `new` calls for `A*` and `B*` and exactly two `delete`s, so if the destructor in `Data` is not deep - and maybe that's where I need clarification, then perhaps this is safe after all and my concern is misplaced? I did notice that the structs `A` and `B` for instance don't have any destructors defined, so I hope it is not deep. But I am not sure if this means their pointer data will be freed up or not. Appreciate expert insights as always.

Thanks for your time and interest.

Comment: `st::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>`.  Problem solved.  Also, `std::shared_ptr<T>` if you need different semantics.

Comment: Also, run valgrind to determine if there are any leaks

Comment: @Ed S: `shared_ptr<const some_type>` indeed looks like a good idea.

Comment: `B* b = new B(sptr)` this line is missing a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` and `B` do not have a user defined destructor, so nothing INSIDE `a` or `b` gets destroyed (other than the actual memory it holds being freed up, but since `sptr` is just held there, it is not being `deleted`). [Obviously, if `A` or `B` contains some other class, say a `std::string` or a `std::vector`, that class would be destroyed].

So, in other words, your code is just fine like it is - `a` and `b` only holds a copy of `sptr`, but it's never deleted [in this bit of code, if it needs deleting later, that's a different matter].

Comment: Thanks, that is reassuring. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`Data::~Data()` will not destroy `sptr` pointer. It will call `A::~A()` and `B::~B()` only.

I'm not sure what you want to do, but if you want a deep destruction you need to make sure you don't free a memory address which was already freed by someone before.

It depends on implementation requirements, but ideally the user who allocated the object should free as well. So since this `sptr` is allocated been by someone else, if you free it you might get a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`sptr` is not owned by either A or B, so this is correct.

Comment: As long as the lifetime of `*sptr` encompasses the lifetime of the `B` and `B` objects using it.

Comment: Indeed, but the question was about the invocation of Data::~Data.

Answer (score 1):

If we shall be really finical then the code *can* leak.

If `d.aptr_list.push_back()` needs and fails to reserve more capacity, then the memory pointed to by `a` and `b` will leak.

```
for(...) {
     some_type *sptr = dynamic_cast<some_type*>(a_source_of_some_type_pointer);
     A* a = new A(sptr);          // Allocate memory
     B* b = new B(sptr)           // Allocate memory (and missing semicolon!!)
     d.aptr_list.push_back(a);    // If this fails,
     d.bptr_list.push_back(b);    // or this,
}                                 // then exception is thrown and memory is lost
                                  // (unless you catch the exception and
                                  // perform a delete).
```

You should use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` to wrap around the pointers for safety.

Your lists should be of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` and `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>`.

In `some_func` the code could read something like this:

```
some_type *sptr = dynamic_cast<some_type*>(a_source_of_some_type_pointer);
d.aptr_list.push_back(std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(sptr)));
d.bptr_list.push_back(std::unique_ptr<B>(new B(sptr)));
```